# Trie vs Radix tree vs Patricia trie

Tags: data-structures, trie, ternary-search-tree, radix-tree, patricia-trie

As I understand (also from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14708134/what-is-the-difference-between-trie-and-radix-trie-data-structures)) memory-complexity of these DSs can be ordered like Trie > Radix > Patricia. But what about time-complexity? I assume they are almost same.

If to mention my problem, I want to do a lot of prefix search queries from pre-constructed dictionary. Memory is not a big concern for me. I want to use the fastest DS.

HAT-trie is best suit for me but it is too complex to implement.
Should I use Ternary Search Trees instead of any DSs mentioned above?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jXAHLqQthKw
Time measure on last slide for Trie and PatriciaTrie
Also PatriciaTrie consumes less memory than Trie

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14708134/what-is-the-difference-between-trie-and-radix-trie-data-structures.